# Index out of bounds exception on quick sort with list of generics

Tags: java, list, sorting, quicksort

This is the code I wrote so far:

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.List;

public class Sorter<T extends Comparable<T>> {
public void sort(List<T> list) {
    if (list.size() <= 10) {
        insertionSort(list, 0, list.size());
    } else {
        quickSort(list, 0, list.size() - 1);
    }
}

private void quickSort(List<T> list, int leftIndex, int rightIndex) {
    int i = leftIndex;
    int j = rightIndex;
    if (i >= j) { 
        return;
    } else if (j - i <= 10) {
        insertionSort(list, i, j+1);
        return;
    }


    int rand = randomizePivot(j, i);
    T pivot = list.get(rand);
    Collections.swap(list, rand, j);

    while (i < j) {

        while (!list.get(i).compareTo(pivot) && i < j) {
            i++;
        }


        while (!pivot.compareTo(list.get(j)) && i < j) {
            j--;
        }


        if (i < j) {
            Collections.swap(list, i, j);
        }
    }

    list.remove(rightIndex);
    list.add(rightIndex, list.get(j));
    list.remove(j);
    list.add(j, pivot);

    quickSort(list, leftIndex, i - 1);
    quickSort(list, j + 1, rightIndex);
}

private int randomizePivot(int hi, int lo) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    return rand.nextInt(hi - lo + 1) + lo;
}

private void insertionSort(List<T> list, int lo, int hi) {
    for (int i = lo + 1; i < hi; i++) {
        int j = i - 1;
        T elem = list.get(i);
        while (j >= lo && list.get(j).compareTo(elem)) {
            list.remove(j + 1);
            list.add(j + 1, list.get(j));
            j--;
        }
        list.remove(j + 1);
        list.add(j + 1, elem);
    }
}

}
```

It "works" nine out ot ten. Sometimes it gives me IndexOutOfBoundsException at this line:

```
        list.add(rightIndex, list.get(j));
```

that's the part where pivot find its definitive position. The exact error message, on a list of 25 items, is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 24, Size: 24
at java.util.LinkedList.checkElementIndex(Unknown Source)
at java.util.LinkedList.get(Unknown Source)
```

Can anyone help? Where's the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can only happen when `rightIndex == j` 
Here you remove the rightmost element and in the next step try to re-insert it. But the `j` index is then gone by the time.

Protect it like thus:

```
if (rightIndex != j) {
       list.remove(rightIndex);
       list.add(rightIndex, list.get(j));
}
```

Comment: yeah, the problem was there, as I pointed out in a comment reply. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @Goet - Good to have this fixed. Sometimes pure logic is more powerful than a debugger. Feel free to upvote helpful answers, it will also increase your own reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Don't add one in the following line `insertionSort(list, i, j+1);`

The easiest way is to change all your methods so that the upper limits are always exclusive (e.g. `quickSort(list, left, right)` or `insertionSort(list, left, right)` will sort all elements from index `left` to `right - 1`, `randomizePivot(lo, hi)` will return a random number in the range from `lo` to `hi - 1`, etc.).

This is an convention that's also used in the java standard libray.

Comment: ...Doing so, not only I get the same message error, but when I don't, the list doesn't result ordered

Comment: You'll have to change more than only this line, because your code interprets upper limits sometimes as included, sometimes as excluded. Work through all your code and check the upper limits!

Comment: Yeah, fixed it! Indexes were right, it was just a simple & stupid thing: when rigthIndex is equals to j, it first removes the j element and then tries to add it! A simple if did the job :)

Answer (score 0):

A list (array in Java) that has a size of 24 cannot have an index of 24 because, indexes will start at zero. This means an array of size 10 will have the indices 0 to 9 and not 1 to 10. Here it looks like that index 24 is requested while the list has index 0 to 23 only.

Comment: Of course your concept about array index is right :) but a list isn't an array and the size of my list is 25. But it doesn't really matter: if it were 49, it would give me error with "index 48, size 48"